# webpages embedded in other webpages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a site that is going to have a lot going on in one page. on one side of the page I want a data input area, in the middle is a separate data input area, and on the left of the page there is an area that continuously should be updating with data from a database.

The area off to the left would be easier to create if it was a separate page, but I need it all in one area.

My question is "is it possible to embed one webpage inside another (almost like a container) and if so, how"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iframe src="otherpage.html">
<iframe src="onemoreotherpage.html">
```

Comment: can I specify where the iframe for each instance will be with css?

Comment: @Andy: Yes. It can be positioned in CSS just like any other element.

Answer (score 2):

you can use an iframe as Phoenix suggests. There are other ways to constantly update from a database and have data be dynamic. You can you xmlhttprequests, web-sockets or eventsource. Here are some links..

eventsource - http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/

web-sockets - http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

xmlhttprequest - http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Comment: Thanks for the information. My question was geared more towards how to actually embed a page into another, but this actually saves me some trouble that I was about to start digging through.... so thanks again